# Scrolling text in edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am facing a strange problem in edittext. I have an edittext in linearlayout, it can have multiple lines of text. When I enter enough text that doesn't make the edittext scrollable, it perfectly goes up when keyboard appears, but when i enter more text e.g. 10 lines that make the edittext scrollable, it hides behind the keyboard whenever i tap on it.I have also used the adjustpan, but no luck.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:hint="Details"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10sp"
                android:paddingRight="10sp"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

manifest is like

```
 <activity
        android:name=".owner.Create_Job_Activity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create__job_" >
    </activity>
```

This linearlayout with edittext is in another linearlayout with weight-sum.

Comment: Include your layout xml and perhaps a screenshot or two so we can see more clearly what's going on

Comment: I have included the layout and manifest code snippets in the question.